# Nautilus Bash Script, how to delete old files after FFMPEG conversion?

Tags: bash, scripts, nautilus, ffmpeg, nautilus-script

I am writing my first ever Nautilus script but I am not sure how to continue. What do I need to add to this nautilus script so that all MP4 files in the folder are deleted **after** FFMPEG finishes converting them to MOV?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" | find '*.mp4'

for i in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -c:v copy -c:a pcm_s16le -ar 48000 -ac 2 "$(echo "$i"|cut -d\. -f1).mov";done
```

Thank you! :)

Comment: A possibly better way to remove and replace the file extension would be `"${i%.*}.mov"` (note this will remove the *shortest* matching suffix - which I'm assuming is what you really want - so for example `other.file.mp4` becomes `other.file.mov` rather than `other.mov`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove (I would prefer with force option enabled) the file - `$i`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" | find '*.mp4'

for i in *.mp4 
do 
    ffmpeg -i "$i" -c:v copy -c:a pcm_s16le -ar 48000 -ac 2 "$(echo "$i"|cut -d\. -f1).mov"
    rm -f "$i"
done
```

- If you wish you can replace the newlines with semicolon `;` sign.

Another option is to [move the file to the trash](https://askubuntu.com/a/525029/566421) instead of delete it:

```
    gvfs-trash "$i"
```

---

In addition, your script can be improved in the following way:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

# Get the items selected in Nautilus as an array
IFS_BAK=$IFS
IFS=$'\t\n'
FILE_LIST=($NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS)
IFS=$IFS_BAK

# For each item in the array $FILE_LIST
for ((i=0; i<${#FILE_LIST[@]}; i++))
do
    # Get the file extension
    FILE_EXT="${FILE_LIST[$i]##*.}"

    # If the item is a file and its extension is mp4 
    if [[ -f ${FILE_LIST[$i]} ]] && [[ $FILE_EXT == 'mp4' ]]
    then
        # Get the filename
        FILE_NAME="${FILE_LIST[$i]%.*}"
        # Compose the name of the new file
        THE_NEW_FILE="${FILE_NAME}.mov"

        # Do the conversion
        ffmpeg -i "${FILE_LIST[$i]}" -c:v copy -c:a pcm_s16le -ar 48000 -ac 2 "$THE_NEW_FILE"

        # Remove the item: rm -f "${FILE_LIST[$i]}"; or move it to the trash:
        gvfs-trash "${FILE_LIST[$i]}"

        # Output a message, note ##*/ will remove the path from the filename
        notify-send "mp4 to mov" "${THE_NEW_FILE##*/} - was created\n${FILE_LIST[$i]##*/} - was moved to the Тrash"
    fi
done
```

---

Here is one related question: [Script to merge Video and subs then delete the existing files](https://askubuntu.com/q/939821/566421)